# Schema for routing based application

Tags: python, database, database-design

I am planning to make a route based application in which I can fill in the following information to get the job done:

1. Enter the source station and time.
2. Enter the destination station.

After filling this the user will get all the metro which go at or after the requested time to the destination station. It works fine for the metro which have a stop at the destination station but the **problem comes when there are metro which doesn't stops at the destination station but they stop at the station before it**, in that case I have to tell the user from where he has to change the metro to get to the destination station.

At present I have the following information:

1. Metro name
2. Station name.
3. Time at which metro stops at that station.

And I created the following schema:

1. metro             # Table which stores the id and metro name
2. station           # Same as above but stores metro info.
3. metro_station     # M2M relation with station and metro along with time.
   eg: metro_station

id metro_id  station_id  time

1    1           1       9:45

2    1           2       9:55

I am confused that should I update the db schema or add some programming logic to achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel? Use Postgres's Routing library:

http://pgrouting.org/

Comment: Thanks @Neil, I will look into it but let me tell you that I am making an android application and I have to use sqlite database.